# On $H_\infty$ norm for transfer function

Tags: math, mimo, control-systems, norm

For a given scenario in the context of control system, I'm trying to investigate how the $H_\infty$ norm can be calculated for a transfer function as follows:
$$G(s)= \frac{w_n^2}{s^2 +2\zeta w_ns +w_n^2  }$$

$$\left \| G \right \| _\infty = \max \limits _{\omega} |G(j\omega)|$$

$$\left \| G \right \| _\infty = \sup \limits _{\omega} |G(j\omega)|$$

I know how to deal with such problems when the  case is specific one, for example the frequency value is known. However, I get confused with this general case. any idea

Comment: Can you try to formulate a specific question? I'm not sure what you're asking us.

Comment: @Marcus Müller, the first one is a transfer function that   the H_infinity norm should be proved in a parametrical form. The next two are the formulas for H_infinity norm.

Comment: So, what is the specific question you're asking? I'm really not sure what you need help with! What's the first step that you don't know how to do?

Comment: @Marcus Müller, Specifically I don't know how to solve this problem manually and not by computer simulation?

Comment: That's not specific.

Comment: Can you say what you *don't* understand about your max and sup formulas? I mean, the answer for "what do I need to calculate" is given by these formulas, explicitly.

Comment: @Marcus Müller, The question is how do I determine the value of 'w'  will the value of $$|G(j\omega)|$$ be maximum?

Comment: @Marcus Müller, Can you introduce me an example of this kind?

Comment: @Rwy5 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima